# Select multiple value in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdownlist (SingleSelection) which retrieve the data from sql database, I want to change it to MultiSelection (select multi value), following is my code.

## ASP.NET

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DrpGroup" runat="server" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

## VB

```
Protected Sub DrpGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DrpGroup.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (DrpGroup.SelectedValue.ToString.Trim.ToUpper <> "PLEASE SELECT...") Then
        Dim cnt_value As Integer = TDES.FindKey("Select Count(*) from dbo.VU_CUSTOMERBYGROUP WHERE upper(ltrim(rtrim(GROUP_NAME)))='" & DrpGroup.SelectedValue.ToString.Trim.ToUpper & "'")
        lblNumberCount.Visible = True
        lblNumberCount.Text = DrpGroup.SelectedValue.ToString.Trim.ToUpper & " has " & CStr(cnt_value) & " member(s). <br /> The cost for this SMS broadcast will be xxx" & CStr(cnt_value * 0.5)
    End If
    If (DrpGroup.SelectedValue.ToString.Trim.ToUpper = "PLEASE SELECT...") Then
        lblNumberCount.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Your efforts would be appreciated.

Comment: `asp:DropDownList` will not support multiple selection directly. Instead of that, you can use `CheckBoxList` or `ListBox` control.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListBox` instead of `DropDownList`

```
<asp:ListBox  runat="server" ID="multiSelect" SelectionMode="multiple" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="option1" Value="option1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="option2" Value="option2"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="option3" Value="option3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```